# MVC 5 button action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

i am new to MVC , do not understand it very good , so please don't use some hard terms.

I have a form that has 2 inputs and 1 input type submit, i want to make a function  which checks if the values in that 2 inputs are the same. Should i write this function in Controller Home if the index is in home?

How do i call that specific function and how do i get that 2 values( from inputs).
I could do this in JavaScript very easily but i need to do it MVC and i have not found any good tutorial to learn this ( so if you know one for beginners please give it to me).

Comment: This would be a good place to learn [model validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model), you could write an attribute that checks if the property matches another defined property.  Look into writing your own custom model validation attribute

Answer (score 2):

First, define a `ViewModel` which represents the data that is exchanged between the Controller and the View (the Controller passes it to the View via the `Controller.View(Object model)` method, and the View passes it back to the Controller via `<form>` submission).

In your case:

```
class HomeViewModel {

    public String FirstValue { get; set; }

    public String SecondValue { get; set; } 

    public String Message { get; set; }
}
```

Your Razor `.cshtml` would look like this:

```
@model HomeViewModel

<p>@( this.Model.Message )</p>

using( Html.BeginForm() ) {

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor( m => m.FirstValue )
        @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.FirstValue )
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor( m => m.SecondValue )
        @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.SecondValue )
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
}
```

Then in your controller's `POST` action/handler you can apply your custom logic:

```
public class HomeController {

    public ActionResult Index() {

        return this.View( new HomeViewModel() );
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HomeViewModel model) {

        if( model == null ) return this.NotFound();

        if( model.FirstValue == model.SecondValue ) {
            model.Message = "Values match";
        }
        else {
            model.Message = "Values are different";
        }

        return this.View( model );
    }
}
```

Note that the `Message` property is one-way because it's never set by the View (as it isn't maintained through any `<input />` element).

Some people, myself included, feel that one-way data should not be in the `ViewModel` but should be in the `ViewData` collection, if so then do it like this:

```
        if( model.FirstValue == model.SecondValue ) {
            this.ViewData["message"] = "Values match";
        }
        else {
            this.ViewData["message"] = "Values are different";
        }

        // 

        <p>@( this.ViewData["message"] )</p>
```

Note that `ViewData` is just a string dictionary, whereas the `ViewModel` is strongly-typed. There is a trick to get strongly-typed `ViewData` but it's a bit complicated and I won't go into it for now.

As the comment in your Question said, if your "values are equal" logic is more concerned with *validation* than actual business-logic then you're better-off using built-in validation attributes, which minimizes the amount of code you need to write:

```
[Compare("OtherPropertyName", ErrorMessage = "The values must match.")]
```

You might also want to add `[DisplayName]` and `[Required]` too:

Like so:

```
class HomeViewModel {

    [DisplayName("First value")]
    [Required]
    public String FirstValue { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Second value")]
    [Required]
    [Compare( nameof(this.FirstValue), ErrorMessage = "Second value must match First value.")]
    public String SecondValue { get; set; } 
}
```

And in your view:

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor( m => m.FirstValue )
    @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.FirstValue )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor( m => m.FirstValue )
</div>

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor( m => m.SecondValue )
    @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.SecondValue )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor( m => m.SecondValue )
</div>
```

And in your `POST` action/handler:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HomeViewModel model) {

    if( !this.ModelState.IsValid ) return this.View( model );

    // ...
```